# Use Wordpress menu in external site

Tags: php, wordpress, perl

I have a wordpress site that is using a custom nav-menu.  I would like to create a .php file in the wordpress folder that only exports , but I can't figure out what else I need to include.

I do NOT want the full header, as this page will be Server Side Included (and included via Perl) into another portion of the site.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Is there a better way to pull the menu from the DB?

All of my searches thus far have returned information about pulling data INTO wordpress, versus out of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a php file in the index on your Wordpress folder. In that file, include `wp-load.php`, then include the function or file you call to include the navbar. From there, you can then execute the file in Perl to include the navbar.

Just note: This is going to completely load Wordpress, which will slow down your Perl execution.

Comment: Perfect.  I was trying to use the wrong include.  A final solution is just a blank php file with: 
<?php include "wp-load.php" ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>